# update two elements in two arrays of same document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document:

```
{ "a" : 9, "b" : [ { "c" : "x", "d" : 8, "k" : 1 }, { "c" : "y", "d" : 2, "k" : 1 } ], "e" : [ { "f" : "u", "g" : 16, "q" : 10 }, { "f" : "v", "g" : 10, "q" : 11 } ] }
```

Now I want to inc a, b.d (where b.c="y" and b.k=1) and e.g (where e.f="u" and e.q=10). So I wrote the update command:

```
db.foo.update({b: {$elemMatch: {c: "y", k: 1}}, e: {$elemMatch: {f: "u", q: 10}}}, {$inc: {a: 1, "b.$.d": 1, "e.$.g": 1}})
```

My expected result:

```
{ "a" : 10, "b" : [ { "c" : "x", "d" : 8, "k" : 1 }, { "c" : "y", "d" : 3, "k" : 1 } ], "e" : [ { "f" : "u", "g" : 17, "q" : 10 }, { "f" : "v", "g" : 10, "q" : 11 } ] }
```

But the real result:

```
{ "a" : 10, "b" : [ { "c" : "x", "d" : 9, "k" : 1 }, { "c" : "y", "d" : 2, "k" : 1 } ], "e" : [ { "f" : "u", "g" : 17, "q" : 10 }, { "f" : "v", "g" : 10, "q" : 11 } ] }
```

b.d was increased where b.c="x" and b.k=1. It's wrong.

How to correct my update command? (mongodb version 2.6.3)

Comment: You need to read the documentation on the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator. This states that only the **first** match will be kept, and that means there can be only one. You cannot match multiple positions.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for reply. Is there any solution for this problem? I want to update both array elements by a single update command.

Comment: Not in a single command there isn't. You can restructure or issue multiple updates.